# Order of Android Private Libraries

Tags: java, android, mockito

For my project it is important that external jars are imported in a specific order. If they are included below Android Private Libraries, then I suspect they are imported in an alphabetic (or random) order. Is it possible to control the order the jars are imported while they are below Android Private Libraries?

**Background**:  it is a test project and I am using Mockito libraries (dexmaker, dexmaker-mockito and mockito-all). As far as I know they are overwriting the same methods, which makes the order significant. When I initially set the order of these libraries (using specific jar imports rather than Android Private Libraries option), it was also specially mentioned that the order is important in the tutorial I followed (sadly I can't find the link any more). If the order is different, I get "Test run failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.IllegalAccessError'".

Comment: "For my project it is important that external jars are imported in a specific order" -- why? What are you trying to accomplish? Bear in mind that you cannot compile a project with multiple definitions of a class, in case you are thinking that by controlling the order you will control what version of a class gets used.

Comment: @CommonsWare it is a test project and I am using Mockito libraries (dexmaker, dexmaker-mockito and mockito-all). I think they are overwriting the same methods. When I initially set the order of these libraries, it was also specially mentioned that the order is important in the tutorial I followed (sadly I can't find the link any more). If the order is different, I get "Test run failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.IllegalAccessError'".

Comment: Oy. I think you're better off asking the Mockito folks.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks, I edited the post accordingly.

Comment: eclipse or android studio?

Comment: @EugenMartynov I am using Eclipse. Is it relevant in this case?

Comment: Yes, As I understood question you need to put your libraries in order in classpath to run tests. But loking closer you're running instrumental tests - so you have to have built apk so there is nothing related to ordering libraries in classpath

Comment: @EugenMartynov I think you are right on this. I found that my problem is not in the order of libraries but some further jars causing the conflict. When I remove these additional libraries, I can run the test project without a problem and the order is not relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find out about the order of libraries, but I solved the problem that caused me to ask this question. 
When I get "Test run failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.IllegalAccessError'" error, it was not because of Mockito related libraries being in wrong order, but because some further libraries in libs folder causing the conflict. When I remove these additional jar-s, everything works well.